# Pass value from one form to another form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to pass `id` from one form to another from in C#.

I am not able to do this.

The C# code is:

```
private void btnedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow a in dataGridViewUnPaidList.Rows) 
    {
        if (a.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            Convert.ToInt64(a.Cells[1].Value); // i have to pass this id in AddInvoice() form
            AddInvoice ad = new AddInvoice();
            ad.Show();
            NonPaideData non = new NonPaideData();
            non.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Now Row Is Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Form1

```
private void ShowForm2()
{
    string value = TheTextBox.Text;
    Form2 newForm = new Form2();
    newForm.TheValue = value;
    newForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Form2

```
private string _theValue;
public string TheValue 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _theValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _theValue = value; 
        // do something with _theValue so that it
        // appears in the UI

    }
}
```

See this code i think this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Make a property in `AddInvoice`:

```
public long CellValue { get; set }
```

Assign to it:

```
private void btnedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow a in dataGridViewUnPaidList.Rows)
    {
        if (a.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            AddInvoice ad = new AddInvoice();
            ad.CellValue = Convert.ToInt64(a.Cells[1].Value);
            ad.Show();

            NonPaideData non = new NonPaideData();
            non.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Now Row Is Selected");
        }
    }
```

And just use it in `AddInvoice` as `CellValue`.

Oh, and if that's actually the code, I think you probably meant `this.Hide();` instead of creating a new `NonPaideData` and hiding that.